# Make new query to have same effect as previous one

Tags: sql, oracle, set-operations

I have the following table:

```
Region_id | Region_name
1           Europe
2           Americas
3           Asia
4           Middle East and Africa
```

And this query:

```
SELECT region_id, region_name
  FROM hr.regions
 GROUP BY CUBE(region_id, region_name);
```

Which returns:

```
Region_id | Region_name
(null)      (null)
(null)      Asia
(null)      Europe
(null)      Americas
(null)      Middle East and Africa
1           (null)
1           Europe
2           (null)
2           Americas
3           (null)
3           Asia
4           (null)
4           Middle East and Africa
```

---

**The question and problem:** How do I make another query that returns the same results as above but using SET operations like union and intersect instead of `group by cube(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use:

```
select region_id, region_name
from hr_regions
union all
select NULL as region_id, region_name
from hr_regions
union all
select region_id, NULL as region_name
from hr_regions
union all
select NULL as region_id, NULL as region_name
from dual;
```

Your example data has not duplicates in either column. so no aggregation or `select distinct` is needed.  The one exception is the last query.  To get only one row with two `NULL` values, it select from `dual`.